# Where is the right layer to add the boost recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I checked on the website below that the boost recipe is on the https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-oe/ layer.

Where is the right layer to add the boost on the image?
/build/conf/local.conf? Or should I extend a new layer to add the boost?
I need the boost to compile the mongodb which is also located on the meta-oe layer.

My bblayers.conf:

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/joao/projetos/toradex/poky/meta \
  /home/joao/projetos/toradex/poky/meta-yocto \
  /home/joao/projetos/toradex/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/joao/projetos/toradex/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/joao/projetos/toradex/poky/meta-fsl-arm \
  /home/joao/projetos/toradex/poky/meta-fsl-arm-extra \
  /home/joao/projetos/toradex/poky/meta-web-kiosk \
  /home/joao/projetos/toradex/poky/meta-web-kiosk-custom \
  "
```

My build/conf/local.conf:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " boost"
```

When I try to add the mongodb I get the error:

```
# bitbake core-image-web-kiosk

NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'mongodb' (but /home/joao/projetos/toradex/poky/meta-web-kiosk/recipes-browser/images/core-image-web-kiosk.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
ERROR: mongodb was skipped: Recipe is blacklisted: Fails to build with system boost
NOTE: Runtime target 'mongodb' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['mongodb']
ERROR: Required build target 'core-image-web-kiosk' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['core-image-web-kiosk', 'mongodb']
```

The boost is compiled, but the mongodb need the boost to compile itself. How can I solve this problem?

Best regards,

Comment: the error said that you have blacklisted mongodb.  Check your local.conf and mongodb_git.bb at poky/meta-oe/recipes-support/mongodb/mongodb_git.bb to look for this line : `INHERIT += "blacklist"` or PNBLACKLIST[mongodb] = " Reason ...".  In addition, show us your local.conf

Comment: There is the line: PNBLACKLIST[mongodb] ?= "Fails to build with system boost". My local.conf: http://pastebin.com/EHB5EYPf. What should I do? Best regards

Comment: boost should not depends on mongodb,  Unless you did something to the recipes.  Delete that line and mongodb would be able to compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bblayers.conf specifies the meta-data (the directories that store the recipes).

local.conf is where you do all the customization, what you want to do for the image for your machine.

So, put `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " boost"` to local.conf.  Note that there is no `+=`.